# No bean named 'aboutus' available, NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

**In WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml:**

```
<beans ...>
     <import resource="view-resolvers.xml"/>
     <import resource="handler-mapper.xml"/>
</beans>
```

**In WEB-INF/spring-mvc.xml:**

```
<beans ...>
     <bean id="aboutus" class="com.myapp.controllers.AboutusController"/>
</beans>
```

**In WEB-INF/handler-mapper.xml:**

```
<beans ...>
     <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
    <props>
         <prop key="aboutus">aboutus</prop>
     </props>
     </property>
 </bean>
</beans>
```

**In web.xml:**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

I'm new to spring. While running spring mvc application with the above configuration I'm getting error as Caused by: `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'aboutus' is defined`. Can any one help me on this. I'm using spring 4.3 version in this app.

Comment: Can anyone tell me whats wrong in this code

Comment: chnage your file name spring-mvc.xml to `spring-mvc-servlet.xml`

Comment: @NawnitSen whats the need of changing the name here

Comment: Spring MVC looks for a file named [servlet-name]-servlet.xml in the WEB-INF directory of your web application and creates the beans defined there.since your servlet name is spring-mvc you need to change the name. can you try once and see if it works.it should i guess

Comment: @NawnitSen just check the `init-param` tag. Without reading the `spring-mvc.xml` file why this error coming

Comment: okay that  i didnt see. for debugging can you just change the className inside the bean (any class which is not present) and see if you get classNotFound exception? if u dont get any such excpn that means its not reading that xml

Comment: @NawnitSen error message clearly tells that container is reading the configuration file. Why I need to check

Comment: Move the `import resource` statements to the `spring-mvc.xml` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like your problem is that you're trying to set up an application context hierarchy with two contexts, one "global" one defined by "applicationContext.xml" and one local to the servlet, defined by "spring-mvc.xml".  When you do that, the servlet application context is the child, and can use any dependencies defined by the "parent" global application context - but not viceversa: the global application context cannot "see" any beans defined by its children.
See, for example: http://javafreakers.com/application-context-level-hierarchy-in-spring-web-application/